# App crash when invoking RecycleView on Fragment

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Okay, I've found many issue about this here (stackoverflow.com/questions/27416834/app-crashing-when-trying-to-use-recyclerview-on-android-5-0), here (stackoverflow.com/questions/26446162/andorid-recyclerview-layoutmanager-exception), or here (code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=81588). I want to comment there, but can't. All of them suggest to set layoutmanager as soon as it inflated. I've done it and the app is still crash and showing this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager.onMeasure(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler, android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$State, int, int) on a null object reference
```

below is my code snippet

**MyFragment.java**

```html
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        myDataset = // initiaized data

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), myDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }
```

**my_fragment.xml**

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" tools:context=".MyFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Have you added `RecyclerView` library into your project's build path ?

Comment: Also check if mRecyclerView is null just after findViewById

Comment: paste complete logcat.

Comment: @GrlsHu It's been there: `compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.+'` @Terence How do I check that? @ dev Ive add logcat

Comment: @stackex how do you show this fragment? please provide the code from activity. Looking at your stacktrace, there is no `onCreateView` call.

Comment: @nikis thanks. My activity really didn't call the fragment

Comment: @stackex then you should close this question, if the issue is resolved

Comment: @nikis I didn't find close button?

Comment: @stackex you can either delete it or you can post the answer by yourself and accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution. Currently I try to provide navigation tab to an activity. Each tab content is shown on a fragment. I try to adapt it from [SDK example](http://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/index.html). The problem is as @nikis said, the adapter didn't call the fragment. According to [this tutorial](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-SlidingTabLayout), I should use adapter that `extends FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `PagerAdapter` as shown in original example. That means that I need to override `getItem` method on `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead of `InstantiateItem` on `PagerAdapter`.

Answer (score 1):

I've reformatted your code a little, it should help you debug further.

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView)
            rootView.findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        if (mRecyclerView != null) {
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2));
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

            myDataset = // initiaized data
            mAdapter = new MyAdapter(
                getActivity().getApplicationContext(), myDataset);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        } else {
            Log.e("Error", "Unable to find recyclerView");
        }
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is *not* a forum. You should have edited the *question*, not posted an *answer*. Read [faq] for more information on how the site works.